# How to add CADRG RPF A.TOC Raster Data Source in Geoserver 2.6

Tags: geoserver, gdal, rpf, cadrg

I'm currently trying to add CADRG as a datasource in Geoserver 2.6.  I've installed the necessary GDAL plugins (1.9.2) for Geoserver 2.6.

I placed my RPF folder in

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\geoserver\data\data\CADRG\RPF` which contains the `a.toc` file and the folders that contain my CADRG tiles.

I'm getting the error

`Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: null`

I know the `a.toc` file is properly created as I've tested it in other software, and the tiles are good as I've viewed them in QGIS 2.4.

As far as I know I have all of the tiles in the correct folders, so I don't think the paths are wrong.  Does anyone have any experience loading CADRG and could help me guide me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

I know my GDAL plugin installation worked correctly as I have been able to add a geoTIFF store successfully, and I know my CADRG tiles are valid as I've been able to add an individual tile as an NITF store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the `a.toc` file with `gdalinfo` and I saw that it said the tiles did not exist.

My directory structure was:

- **RPF**

  - **CHARTS**

    - **CHTSERIES**
- a.toc

Turns out I needed the `CHARTS` folder to be in the parent folder with the `a.toc` file, not in the `RPF` folder.  I did this, and I was able to create the store.